# Best backend technologies for Broadcast Push notifications android from web application

Tags: android, database, push-notification, backend

I need to make an application for android for firefighters, with a simple login (without registration), and a simple web application, which with a panic button, that sends a notification to all registered users (registrations are made by an admin from the application Web)

Is there any way to do it with django rest framework and react native?

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) is the recommended way to send notifications on Android. As it turns out, you can use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs) as your complete server solution as well -- web, Android, iOS. There is a ton of documentation, blogs, and YouTube tutorials on Firebase.